# powermock runs into Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am using junit 4.12, mockito 1.10.9, powermock 1.6.6
The same combination of version works else where in another project.

I run into exception..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(OfsClientUtilities.class)
public class deleteme {

@Test
public void getAverageTest() throws IOException {
    Client client = mock(Client.class);
    Invocation.Builder target = mock(Invocation.Builder.class);
    Response response = mock(Response.class);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(OfsClientUtilities.class);

    Mockito.when(OfsClientUtilities.getOfsRestClient(any(), anyString(), 
    anyString())).thenReturn(target);

    Mockito.when(target.get()).thenReturn(response);
    Mockito.when(response.getStatus()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

    String jsonString = deleteme.read("somefile.json");

    Mockito.when(response.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(jsonString);
....}
```